# Quickly stop all network services except sshd (or boot with only sshd running)

Tags: services, upstart, runlevel

I have an Ubuntu Server 12.04 box acting as a home file server. At times I would like to be able to brings down all my normal network services (nfs-kernel-server and friends, netatalk, nmbd, smbd, backuppc, subsonic, and transmission-daemon) without bringing down sshd. I would also like to be able to boot the machine without starting all of these services but *with* sshd running.

Before upstart, this would have been simple. Set the default runlevel to 3. Set the above-mentioned network services to start at runlevels 3-5, but not 2. Leave sshd starting at 2-5. Then, to bring down everything except sshd, run `telinit 2`. Or to boot without starting all those services, append `3` to the kernel command line.

However, some of these services (idmapd, statd, rpcbind, nmbd, and smbd) have been converted to upstart jobs. As a test, I tried adding `and runlevel [345]` to the start condition of smbd and nmbd, but it didn't seem to do anything:

```
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up and runlevel [345])
stop on runlevel [!345]
```

What am I missing? How can I get these upstart jobs to respond to runlevel changes?